# На локальной машине код работает стабильно, но на сервере выходит ошибка! chatGPT

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, chatgpt

Хочу протестировать работу данного репозитория на GitHub -> https://github.com/n3d1117/chatgpt-telegram-bot
На локальной машине код работает стабильно, но на сервере выходит ошибка:

```
Exception while handling an update: Message is too long
```

Я понимаю, что она обозначает, но не понимаю причину её возникновения именно на сервере!
Как думаете, в чём может быть проблема? Все зависимости установлены (но, я уверен, что дело не в них)

Вот полная ошибка:
https://pastein.ru/t/JlV

Comment: Версии (питона и пакетов) на локальной машине те же что и на сервере? Добавьте отладочный вывод всех обращений к openai_helper (и возвращаемых значений). Проверьте что на сервере и на локальной машине на одни запросы даются одни ответы.

Comment: HTML код что ли присылается в сообщении? Так он очень длинный. В телеграм есть ограничение на количество символов - до 4096